# How to solve Cannot load 'mcMath.dll' [126]?

Tags: c#, dll, mql4, mql5

I have writtten this simple `.DLL` in **`C#`**

```
namespace mcMath
 {
     public class Class1
     {
        public static double addUp(double num1, double num2)
         {
             return (num1 + num2);
         }

    }
 }
```

when I try to **`#import`** this `.DLL` file to a <kbd>MetaTrader4</kbd> platform `MQL4` code, I get an error:

> `Cannot load 'mcMath.dll' [126]`.

```
    10:55:17.373    Expert fadi EURUSD,H4: loaded successfully
0   10:55:17.689    Expert fadi EURUSD#,H1: loaded successfully
3   10:55:19.224    Cannot load 'mcMath.dll' [126]
0   10:55:19.225    fadi EURUSD,H4: initialized
3   10:55:24.027    Cannot load 'mcMath.dll' [126]
0   10:55:24.028    fadi EURUSD#,H1: initialized
1   10:55:27.463    Cannot call 'mcMath.dll::addUp', 'mcMath.dll' is not loded    
1   10:55:27.494    fadi EURUSD#,H1: unresolved import function call
0   10:55:27.522    fadi EURUSD#,H1: uninit reason 4
0   10:55:27.538    Expert fadi EURUSD#,H1: removed
```

I have allowed `DLL` imports in the platform options.

**`Q1:`** Does anybody have the same problem?
**`Q2:`** How to solve it?

**`MQL4`** code:

```
   #import "mcMath.dll"
   double addUp(double number1,double number2);
   #import
   double number1, number2;
   int OnInit()
   {
  //---
      number1=10.5;
      number2=20.3;
      double number3= addUp(number1,number2);
      Print("the result is: " + number3);
   //---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
    }
```

Comment: Are you p-invoking **mcmath.dll**?  If so show us your import statement

Answer (score 0):

**A1:** No, there is not any general answer valid to this question.

**A2:** Let's create a check-list of items, that have to be met, so as to `#import` from DLL:

1. MetaTrader4 Terminal permit to use (import) from DLL ... PASS
2. location of a said DLL file ... TBD
3. a call-signature matching of DLL exported function(s) ... TBD

For the sake of [2], always check, that you have placed a file, containing your DLL of choice, to a `<TerminalDir>/MQL4/Libraries` folder.

For the sake of isolation the [3], always use a trivial, parameter-less integration test function and validate a proper return value `int test_DLL_LOADED(){ return( 1 ); }` in `MQL4` code:

```
#import "<aDllFileNAME>"                       // MQL4 pre-processor directive
                        int test_DLL_LOADED(); // DLL  parameter-less signature
                         ...                   //      other signatures of import'd f()
#import                                        // MQL4 pre-processor directive


int OnInit(){
    if ( !test_DLL_LOADED() ){
       // FAILED:                              // CLOSE ALL FILE-IOs
                                               // SEND SIGs / MESSAGEs TO PEERs
                                               // UPDATE GLOBAL VARIABLEs
                                               // LOG EVENT
                                               // GET READY FOR A GRACEFUL EXIT
          ...
       // EXIT:
          ExpertRemove();
    }
 // PASSED: PROCEED WITH A NEXT INTENDED SETUP STEP
    ...

}
```